# Javascript fetch is not working, postman works fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, postman, multer

I have route where I can upload images, and it works fine with postman.
I`m using multer as middleware.

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("file", "");

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
});

xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/file");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Postman-Token", "a6e7543e-ef94-4d17-813d-a0a1fb4aa2b2");

xhr.send(data);
```

but when I`m using fetch in my react app it just return undefined

```
uploadImage = async (image) => {
const imageData = new FormData()
imageData.append('file', image)
  const address = '/file'
  const body = imageData
  const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080${address}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    body: body
  })
  const result = await response.json()
  return result
}
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

I copy paste request from postman to my react app, it still doesn`t work.

Comment: Well when I set headers I had error `{"message":"Multipart: Boundary not found"}`. I read about it, and fetch should set headers by itself.
I checked it and node receive good header `'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarywtyu7gt8JIFxKKRT'`

Comment: Well as you can see above server receive good headers with good boundary.

Comment: Postman workis fine without content-type too.